# Push array into list flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So i'm trying to create a list with objects of type 'MessageListItem'. I'm trying to push data returned from my API into the list. The variable I want it pushed into is 'messages'. I am getting an error in the 'getMessages()' function.

The error I am getting is: ***A value of type 'MessageListItem' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.***

The API call & code is:

```
List<MessageListItem> messages;

getMessages() async {
    List<MessageListItem> res = MessageListItem.fromJson(await getMessageList()); 
    // I'm getting the error on the line above. 
    print(res);
  }

Future<dynamic> getMessageList() async {
  final response = await http.get(baseUrl + 'message/jxchumber');
  print(response.statusCode);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var res = json.decode(response.body);
    return res;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to get data');
  }
}
```

MessageListItem Class

```
class MessageListItem {
  int id;
  int senderId;
  int recipientId;
  String senderUsername;
  String recipientUsername;
  int itemId;
  String messageContentString;
  bool read;
  dynamic dateTimeSent;

  MessageListItem(
      {this.id,
      this.senderId,
      this.recipientId,
      this.senderUsername,
      this.recipientUsername,
      this.itemId,
      this.messageContentString,
      this.read,
      this.dateTimeSent});

  factory MessageListItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MessageListItem(
      id: json['id'],
      senderId: json['senderId'],
      recipientId: json['recipientId'],
      senderUsername: json['senderUsername'],
      recipientUsername: json['recipientUsername'],
      itemId: json['itemId'],
      messageContentString: json['messageContentString'],
      read: json['read'],
      dateTimeSent: json['dateTimeSent'],
    );
  }
}
```

The data being returned from the API is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "senderId": 1,
        "recipientId": 3,
        "senderUsername": "jxchumber",
        "recipientUsername": "pavster31",
        "itemId": 0,
        "messageContentString": "hello1",
        "read": false,
        "dateTimeSent": "2020-12-14T22:23:55.1473414"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "senderId": 1,
        "recipientId": 9,
        "senderUsername": "jxchumber",
        "recipientUsername": "larsen",
        "itemId": 0,
        "messageContentString": "hello1",
        "read": false,
        "dateTimeSent": "2020-12-14T16:04:50.8232055"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to push it into the variable 'messages'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 getMessages() async {
    var list = await getMessageList();
    List<MessageListItem> res = list.map((i)=>MessageListItem.fromJson(i)).toList();
 }
```